# Error al correr npm run dev en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Alguna solución??? me sale este este error al poner el comando npm run dev

```
$ npm run dev

> proyecto-node@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\ianhd\Desktop\proyecto-node
> C:/Users/ianhd/Desktop/proyecto-node/src/views/nodemon index.js

"C:/Users/ianhd/Desktop/proyecto-node/src/views/nodemon" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> C:/Users/ianhd/Desktop/proyecto-node/src/views/nodemon index.js

"C:/Users/ianhd/Desktop/proyecto-node/src/views/nodemon" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! proyecto-node@1.0.0 dev: `C:/Users/ianhd/Desktop/proyecto-node/src/views/nodemon index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the proyecto-node@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ianhd\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-07T01_50_19_407Z-debug.log
```

Estos son mis archivos de package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proyecto-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

He intentado ya varias soluciones, como eliminar package.lock.json y la carpeta node modules y volver a instalar, también npm install -g cross-env o npm update. Y ninguna de ellas me ha funcionado. No sé que más probar...

Comment: Algo esta mal en tus carpetas, muestranos la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto (no es necesario que incluyas lo que hay dentro de node_modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estas colocando mal la dirección del index.js, ya que si te fijas, esta accediendo a la carpeta src/views, y en el script "dev" colocaste src/index.js.
Modifica la direccion asi :

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/views/index.js"
  }
```